# SSH to Icinga2 server doesn't work sadly

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ssh

I had SSH working towards my server on port 50509, but it suddently stopped working. I were installing Icinga2, MySQL and Apache2. After the installation, it stopped working.
SSH/SSHD SSH.service/SSHD.service is running.
Ping works just fine between the servers.

From my Windows client:

```
C:\Users\Username>ssh username@172.22.10.133 -p 50509
ssh: connect to host 172.22.10.133 port 50509: Connection timed out
C:\Users\Username>ssh username@172.22.10.133 -p 22
ssh: connect to host 172.22.10.133 port 22: Connection refused

C:\Users\Username>telnet 172.22.10.133 22
Connecting to 172.22.10.133...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22 : Connection failed 
C:\Users\Username>telnet 172.22.10.133 50509
Connecting to 172.22.10.133...Could not open connection to the host, on port 50509 : Connection failed
```

On the Ubuntu Server:

```
username@servername:~/Desktop$ sudo ufw status 
[sudo] password for user: 
Status: inactive
username@servername:~/Desktop$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
username@servername:~/Desktop$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
50509                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
50509 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

username@servername:~/Desktop$ sudo ufw allow ssh
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
username@servername:~/Desktop$ sudo lsof -i:50509
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1095 root    3u  IPv4  27587      0t0  TCP *:50509 (LISTEN)
sshd    1095 root    4u  IPv6  27589      0t0  TCP *:50509 (LISTEN)      
username@servername:~/Desktop$ ip add | grep 172.22.10.133 
inet 172.22.10.133/24 brd 172.22.10.255 scope global noprefixroute ens160
```

I've listed the port 50509 in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config. But I don't even get the connection prompting for password, as I did earlier, it just times out. I've also sat up Google Auth, which also worked.
But again, not related I think. I tried to both disable/enable the ufw firewall, without any help. Also tried booting both server and PC.

I can connect directly via LOOPBACK on the server through ssh on the port.

Wireshark shows be the following in regards to the connection:

```
233 8.471572    172.22.11.131   172.22.10.133   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 53076 → 50509 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

234 8.472026    172.22.10.133   172.22.11.131   ICMP    94  Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)
```

Could it be something on the CheckPoint router (packet forwarding) that stops it?

I've set Everyone can Everyone between 172.22.10.x and 172.22.11.x in the CP, both ways.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you connect via loopback directly on the server ex. `ssh username@localhost -p 50509`?

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your question rather than posting it in comments

Comment: Thanks for your input @steeldriver

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by adding firewall-cmd and iptables commands to the Ubuntu server. :D @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

Adding firewall-cmd and iptables commands to the Ubuntu server resolved the issue with the:

```
ssh: connect to host 172.22.10.133 port 50509: Connection timed out
```

Now:

```
C:\Users\Username>ssh username@172.22.10.133 -p 50509
Password:
Verification code:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.10 (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-26-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

6 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Last login: Thu Oct 29 10:01:44 2020 from 172.22.11.131
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.10 (GNU/Linux 5.8.0-26-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

6 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Last login: Thu Oct 29 10:01:44 2020 from 172.22.11.131
```